# Thread building block library vc11_ui?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tbb, visual-c++-2012

I recently downloaded TBB41_20130613 (current release for Windows at this time), and I noticed that there are folders for `vc11` and `vc11_ui` bin/lib folders. As far as I can tell, both have the same libraries (file names are the same), but they are clearly different binaries (different file sizes). I haven't found any reference in the documentation or via Google what's the difference between the two.

What's the difference between the two? When should I use one over the other, or must I reference both at the same time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These (vc11_ui) are binaries to build windows store applications
More details can be found in the blog [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/windows-8-tutorial-writing-a-multithreaded-application-for-the-windows-store-using-intel-0).